# How to Disable control till Progress Bar is active

Tags: java, android, view, progress-bar, visibility

I have kept progressbar visibility to `invisible` from xml. Its respective activity have a Asynch Task when in `onPreExecute` its visibility is turn out to `visible` and `invisible` in `onPostExecute`. All working fine, however I want my other view control remains disable till progressbar is visible.

**Xml**

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleInverse"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: just try this line for all of the views you want to disable.

view.setEnable(false);

Comment: Y dont you use ProgressDialog then??

Comment: @Namecan'tbedisplayed because dont want to show that background area of dialog

Comment: @VarunVishnoi, can you see my comment above, just try it once...

Comment: Use translucent Theme to the Dialog!

Comment: @SalmanKhan Can you post some as answer.

Comment: @VarunVishnoi, you can accept the answer if you find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are having a Asynch Task, it should have the following methods :-

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

       // Disable the progress bar
      progress.setVisibility(false);

      // Enable all the views that you have disabled earlier in onPreExecute
      view1.setEnable(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        // start progress bar here
        progress.setVisibility(true);

       // Disable all your views here

       view1.setEnable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    }
```

Here progress is an object of ProgressBar and view1 will be your viewgroup it may be a Imageview, Textview or anything else.

Comment: This works fine...when the xml has single view other than the ProgressBar...if the xml contains more than 2 or 3 views, then??

Comment: Then just make parent layout as disable.

Comment: disabling parent layout doesnt mean that child view doesnt work

Comment: if you have a relative layout as a parent layout then take its id and set the setEnable method to false, it should reflect to all of the child views.

Comment: Please try it out... Child views are enabled.. They are not dependent on parent view. We have to set enable all child views explicitly and that is good good approach